# in c# how to assign a superscript to an equation?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2005, console-application

i have an equation that requires a number to be multiplied by itself for the given number of times ,
   like:

```
 2 ^ 5

but if i implement the carrot '^' sign it doesnt give the required result ...
```

am i doing it wrong ?

if so what will be the correct expression for it?

Comment: +1 for "carrot" :D I think you mean "caret" - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In C#, `^` is the 'exclusive or' operator. For exponentiation you need to use `Math.Pow()`:

`double d = Math.Pow(2, 5);`

Comment: thank's , i'm new to c# so having trouble figuring such things out ..
;)

Answer (score 5):

Use `Math.Pow(2, 5)`

The carrot sign "^" is used for boolean and bitwise exclusive-OR operations. Your idea that it's used to calculate the power comes from VB/VB.NET.